# Converting Wire Protocol from Oracle to Postgres and Vice-Versa

Tags: postgresql, oracle, goldengate, protocol

Naive Question

Assume we have an Application which was originally written for ORACLE as DBMS. If I want write an intermediary layer that gives this application independence to be able to work with PostgreSQL DBMS - I presume that I would be required to perform the following :

```
SQL : Application--> ODBC API (Oracle Wire Protocol) --> My Layer ---> ODBC API (PostgreSQL Wire Protocol)
Response : Application-->ODBC API (Oracle Wire Protocol)<--- My Layer <--- (PostgreSQL Wire Protocol)PostgreSQL DBMS
```

1. Is such a layer sensible?
2. Who else has done this?
3. What are the challenges we need to tackle?
4. For ANSI compliant SQL queries will it be sufficient if one simply replaces the ODBC Driver for PostgreSQL. So that scenario changes to :

   SQL : Application--> ODBC API (PostgreSQL Wire Protocol) ----> PostgreSQL DBMS
   Response : Application-->ODBC API (PostgreSQL Wire Protocol) <---- PostgreSQL DBMS

Comment: I don't think that will work at all. You will have to rewrite the queries that use Oracle-specific SQL syntax.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe That's true for Oracle specific syntax, however, I was more worried about standard/ANSI compliant queries.

Comment: Even then, not all databases apply the same version of the ANSI standard. You're still potentially going to have the same problem.

Comment: If the app is already using the most basic SQL, why not just use the PostgreSQL ODBC driver directly. From the app perspective ODBC is ODBC, regardless of the back-end database: you've already achieved independence at the wire protocol level. The only thing that would potentially *be* different is your SQL syntax, which you won't be able to correct with a wire protocol conversion anyway.

Comment: @pmdba +1 Agree. That is why I mentioned about simply replacing the driver. But I am/was not sure on, even if ODBC APIs are same, there could be some behavioral difference in the driver which could cause applications to misbehave.

Comment: Right. But you won't be able to solve that with an automatic query rewrite. You'll most likely have to modify the application.

Comment: Keep in mind that the only job of the ODBC driver/wire protocol is to get the bits from the client to the server and back. It has nothing to do with the *content* of those bits or how the server will interpret them. If there's a potential issue with the SQL itself, you'll have to modify the application code. At best, ANSI only gets you so far; if you're doing anything that makes a database like Oracle (or PostgreSQL or any other real DB) *special* and worth the licensing investment then you've left ANSI behind.